# UI Router not working with Angular not matter what

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

(angularJS 1.2.5 & ui-router 0.2.7)
Please help its 4 in the morning and its been 2-3hrs since i'm stuck with this, flipped the code multiple times but cudn't make it run.
In my `index.html`, I have the following code:

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav sidebar-slide">
   <ul class="nav nav-list" style="font-size:17px">
      <li class="nav-header">Demand Type</li>
        <li><a ui-sref="add14" data-toggle="tab">ADD-14</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="cash_purchase" data-toggle="tab">Cash Purchase</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="local_purchase" data-toggle="tab">Local Purchase</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

        <div class="hero-unit" ui-view></div>
```

In my `app.js`, I have the following code:

```
var ODS = angular.module('ODS', ['ui.router','ngAnimate']);
    //Define Routing for app
    ODS.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
          // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1

        $urlRouterProvider
            .when('/add14', '/add14/create_order')
            .when('/cp', '/cp/create_order')
            .when('/lp', '/lp/create_order')
            .otherwise("/intro");
        $stateProvider
            .state('intro', {
                url: "/intro",
                templateUrl: "templates/core/intro.html"
            })
            .state("add14", {
                url: '/add14',
                templateUrl: 'templates/core/add14.html'
            })
                .state("add14.create_order", {
                    url: "/create_order",
                    templateUrl: "templates/ADD14/add14.create_order.html"
                })
                .state("add14.own_demand", {
                    url: "/own_demand",
                    templateUrl: "templates/ADD14/add14.own_demand.html"
                })
    }]);
```

In my `add14.html`, I have following code:

```
<a ui-sref=".create_order">Create</a></button>
<a ui-sref=".own_demand">Own Demand</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

In my `add14.create_order.html` & `add14.own_demand.jsp` i have sample code to print.
Thank You for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever get this figured out? I'm running into a similar problem - I find that using `<a href='#/url'>` seems to work, but I can't access my states via ui-sref either. I've also noticed that the rendered html doesn't auto-generate an href corresponding to the state as the documentation said it would. Fairly confused why it's not working myself.

Comment: Yes, it was a conflict between the versions, update to the latest ones and see how it goes!

Comment: Version error for me too. I was using ngBoilerplate which used 0.0.1 of ui-router. Fairly straight forward fix after that.

Answer (score 1):

Heads up: try to make sure you add the "ng-app" directive to your body tag (in your main template), otherwise, it seems angular-ui-router stuff, such as the ui-sref directive, will not be called.

Example:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">...</html><!-- Nope. Don't do this -->


<html>...<body ng-app="myApp"></body></html><!-- Do this instead -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using both $stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider. try just using $stateProvider instead of both as that could be where your error is. And you don't have controllers for each of your states. Hope this helps you.

Comment: it was a conflict between the versions, update to the latest ones and see how it goes!